# PHPUnit Selenium tests fail on Docker localhost and pass using public IP

Tags: selenium, networking, docker, ip, phpunit

I'm trying to setup an automated testing platform with Docker and Selenium Grid. 
In the diagram below you can see the structure that I'm using. 
On top is the ubuntu server running on Compute Engine. 
On the left is a docker container running ubuntu 14.04. 
The container runs our project on localhost:8080 with Google App Engine. 
On the right is the Selenium Hub with two nodes running on port 4444.

[image: Selenium Setup]

There is portforwarding from the host to the docker aswell as to the selenium hub. On 32772 and 32768 respectively.

When running my Selenium tests I send them to the hub, which in its turn will run the tests on the localhost of the docker.
My problem is that when I tell the hub to run the tests on 172.17.0.2:8080 it opens the startup screens, but it can't submit any forms.
When I submit the form the text areas get cleared. Like the page is refreshed in some way. The strange thing is that when I tell the hub to use the external ip of the host and the port of the docker like this xx.xx.xx.xx:32772, it does work.
And it has all the functionality. However for performance and automation reasons I'd like to run it on the internal ip adress.

Any help would be appreciated.

Tijn

Comment: How have you bound your container ports to your host's ports?

Comment: I've tried both ways, by mapping them to a port of my choice like this 'docker run -p 8888:8080 myimage' , but in this scenario it's done with the automatic port forwarding. so just the -p 8080 tag.

Comment: How do you serve the content? are you using nginx? if that's the case . what is the config?

Comment: If you mean as in what is the website hosted on, it's Google App Engine SDK.

Comment: I am asking because maybe the host ip matters to your application not the infrastructure. for example if you define a host name in nginx, it will not respond to other hostnames for that particular request.

Comment: This is the command used to boot up the webserver : google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php5-cgi --php_gae_extension_path=appengine-php-extension/modules/gae_runtime_module.so ./my-map/ --host 0.0.0.0 --skip_sdk_update_check . I don't think that it doesn't respond to other hosts because I can actually reach the website through the internal ip adress (screenshots, and pinging), but some of the functionality appears to be missing.

Comment: can you monitor the full payload? is it a web request not responding well or is it an asset not loading for example?

Comment: Everything appears to be loaded, I have functionality on the home screen.  I just can't login or register, whenever I want to submit a form the text areas appear to get cleared. Do note this is based on screenshots, as I can't reach the internal ip adress with a GUI. I'm letting my tests take screenshots in between actions. And I'm monitoring these.

Comment: I suggest you login into one of those containers and view the request logs with `docker exec -it {container_id} /bin/bash` specifically look for error logs and see what is missing

Comment: @MiadAbrin You put me on the right track by saying it was a problem with the application serving the content. The problem was in the .env file. The Session Domain was set to the host ip. When I changed it to the internal ip adress it worked as it should. Thanks!

Comment: Was a pleasure. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my .env file. The Session Domain was set to the host ip instead of the internal ip adress. By changing it, the website worked like it should.